# Android: SurfaceView is blocking navigation drawer

Tags: android, android-fragments, surfaceview, navigation-drawer

My surfaceview is blocking my navigation drawer from appearing.

My main activity has a fragment that sets its content view as the surface view:

```
getActivity().setContentView(surfaceView);
```

that same main activity also creates a navigation drawer:

Java:

```
    drawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawerLayout);

    actionBarDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, drawerLayout,
            R.drawable.ic_navigation_drawer, R.string.drawer_open,
            R.string.drawer_close) {

        @Override
        public void onDrawerClosed(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerClosed(drawerView);
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
            super.onDrawerOpened(drawerView);   
        }

        @Override
        public void onDrawerSlide(View drawerView, float slideOffset){
            drawerLayout.bringChildToFront(drawerView);
            drawerLayout.requestLayout();
        }
    };

    drawerLayout.setDrawerListener(actionBarDrawerToggle);
    getSupportActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
```

XML:

```
    <android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout 
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"

    android:id="@+id/drawerLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <FrameLayout
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:id="@+id/mainContent"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">
    </FrameLayout>

    <ListView
        android:background="#00000000"
        android:id="@+id/drawerList"
        android:layout_width="320dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_gravity="left">
    </ListView>

    </android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

any other alternative approaches to achieve a navigation drawer or navigation drawer look alike while still maintaining a surface view are welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When your Fragment calls this line: `getActivity().setContentView(surfaceView);`, it is replacing the Activity's layout containing the DrawerLayout with only the SurfaceView. That is, your Activity no longer has a DrawerLayout. Your Fragment should be loading the SurfaceView into its own layout in `onCreateView()`.